# pandas add one column to many others

Tags: pandas

I want to add the values of one column

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame(data={"a":[1,2],"b":[102,4], "c":[4,5]})

# what I intended to do                      
df[["a","b"]] = df[["a","b"]] + df[["c"]]
```

Expected result:

```
df["a"] = df["a"] + df["c"]
df["b"] = df["b"] + df["c"]
```

You can assume a list of columns is available (`["a", "b"]`). is there a non loop / non line by line way of doing this? must be...

Comment: Is `df["b"] = df["a"] + df["c"]` correct?

Comment: yes you are right, thx, edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) with `axis=0` and select `c` column only one `[]` for `Series`:

```
df[["a","b"]] = df[["a","b"]].add(df["c"], axis=0)
print (df)
   a    b  c
0  5  106  4
1  7    9  5
```